# Why is Type Inference not applied?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

In this case, *type inference* works as expected, and the `T` *type parameter* handles both `Integer` and `String`:

```
public class A {
    public static <T> void func(T obj1, T obj2) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.func(1, "One");
    }
}
```

However, the same does not seem to apply in the following example, as a *compilation error* occurs:

```
class Test<T> {
    private T object;
    public Test(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}

public class A {
    public static <T> void func(Test<T> one, Test<T> two) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> one = new Test<>(1);
        Test<String> two = new Test<>("Two");
        A.func(one, two);  //compilation error
        //A.<Object>func(one, two);
    }
}
```

Even though *(for example)* `Test<Object>` could handle both `Test<Integer>` and `Test<String>`, the `T` type parameter isn't *inferred*. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you enforced a strict `Test<T> one, Test<T> two`, and those `T` values must match. If you want to support bounded types, you'd need `Test<? extends T>` at minimum, and off the top of my head that may not work without the type witness (the `<Object>` in `A.<Object>func(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though (for example) Test could handle both Test and Test, the T type parameter isn't inferred. Why does this happen?

Nope. Wrong.

Generics is **invariant**. That means only the exact type will do. A subtype will not do. In contrast, 'normal' java is *covariant* - a subtype will do whenever one of its parent types is required.

Try it. Program along - compile this stuff and run it:

```
Integer i = 5;
Number n = i; // no problem

List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // compiler error!
```

The reason it's a compiler error is because that is nonsense. **If** it was allowed (and fortunately it is not!), then.. let's continue:

```
Double d = 5.5;
Number dn = d; // this is fine.
numbers.add(dn); // this has to be. I add a Number to a List<Number>
```

But.. we just messed up. `numbers` and `ints` aren't clones of each other. They are references to the same list. It's like an address book entry: You and I have our own address books but we wrote the same address. There's 2 address books, 2 pages, both with the same address, so only one house. If you walk over to the address in your book and toss a brick through the window, and then I walk over to my address, i.. notice the broken window. Same here: That `numbers.add(dn)` also changes what `ints` sees because **they reference the same list**. So, it's also added to the thing `ints` points at which.. is a problem! We just added a `Double` to a `List<Integer>`.

**This is why generics are invariant**.

In your first example it 'works' because java can infer `T is Object` and then all works well. The second example does not work because nothing can be inferred that works - invariance means `T is object` **will not** actually work. Change it to this:

```
public static <T> void func(Test<? extends T> one, Test<? extends T> two) {}
```

Then it would work fine. Each question mark is its own thing, so, one can be different from the other one, and both `Integer` and `String` are subtypes of Object, so T now *can* be `Object`.

`? extends T` is basically 'I want covariance, not invariance'.

Which is fine. And the compiler will stop you from making boneheaded mistakes. Code along:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> numbers = ints; // this DOES compile!

Number n = 5.5;
numbers.add(n); // This doesn't though!
```

To stop you from ruining type safety, you can't add *anything* to a `List<? extends Whatever>` (and remember that `<?>` is short for `<? extends Object>`, so also applies there). No `.add()` call works. Except literally `.add(null)` (where `null` is not 'some value that happens to resolve to null', no this is a compile time thing: Only literally the letters n, u, l, l - and that's only because the `null` literal is every type all at once).

Answer (score 1):

`func` requires that both `Test` instances passed to it have the *same* type (named `T`), but `one` and `two` have different types.

It should more clear if you use a different name for the type of func:

```
public static <X> void func(Test<X> one, Test<X> two) {}
```

The type for `X` is determined at the call point.

Just using the same name `T` as is used in `Test` has no effect.